# I cannot use java array.remove() on int[]

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java, and I am in a class where for the homework, I need to remove duplicate elements in an array, but I have come across an obstacle in my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot invoke remove(int) on the array type int[]

    at File10.main(File10.java:17)
```

This is my code so far:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Homework10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arrayLength = (int) (Math.random()*50);
        int[] randomArray = new int[arrayLength];
        for (int i =0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
            randomArray[i] = (int) (Math.random()*20);
        }
        System.out.println("Original Array:");
        for (int i =0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
            System.out.print(randomArray[i] + " ");
        }
        for (int i =0; i<randomArray.length; i++) {
            for (int k =(i + 1); k<randomArray.length; k++) {
                if (randomArray[i] == randomArray[k]) {
                    randomArray.remove(k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything I have checked either does not relate to my code or proves that there shouldn't be an error in my code.

Comment: In Java, an array and an `ArrayList` are two different things. An array is fixed length, and an `ArrayList` is a dynamic length. There is no `remove` for an array.

Comment: When I tried to switch my array to ```ArrayList```, a separate error comes up

Comment: What is the separate error?

Comment: never mind, I figured everything out transferring my array to ArrayList, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `remove()` method on an array. Use an ArrayList, or read the [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) on arrays.